# accessing data from a series

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

Okay. This might be lame and silly doubt for most of you.
I have trouble in accessing the values from column index 1 in the variable 'true_p'.This is how the variable looks like.

```
true_p.head()
507     80.0
2920    44.6
1464    74.7
1158    74.8
282     56.5
Name: life_exp, dtype: float64
```

Now i need to access the values in column in 1st index(i.e, 80.0, 44.6, 74.7 etc) and add it in another dataframe.
PS: true_p is a variable that is obtained from train_test_split() function where I've placed true prediction values in this variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the values like this, using `.values`:

```
import pandas as pd

index = [
    507,
    2920,
    1464,
    1158,
    282
]

true_p = pd.Series([
    80.0,
    44.6,
    74.7,
    74.8,
    56.5,
], index=index)

print(true_p.values)
```

Returning:

```
[80.  44.6 74.7 74.8 56.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas.Series.tolist` for getting a series of values list

```py
import pandas as pd
true_p = pd.Series([80.0, 44.6, 74.7,74.8 , 56.5], index=[507, 2920, 1464,1158,282])
value_list=true_p.tolist()
print(value_list)
```

```
[80.0, 44.6, 74.7, 74.8, 56.5]
```